# Demostration with the laplacian

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is an integer function and that $u (x,y)$ and $v(x, y)$ are of class $C^2$ in $\Bbb R^2$

Show that

[image]

I've done:

Since $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is an integer function, $f$ is differenciable

$$f'(z) = (∂u/∂x) + i (∂v/∂x)$$

$$4|f'(z)| = 4((∂u/∂x)^2+(∂v/∂x)^2)$$

And

$$Δ|f(z)|^2 = Δ(u^2+v^2) =  (∂^2u/∂x^2)+(∂^2v/∂x^2) =                   (∂u/∂x)^2+(∂v/∂x)^2$$

This expressions are obviouly not igual... Could someone say me what i've done wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "integer function"? I would normally take this to mean a function whose domain and/or range is $\Bbb Z$, but that's clearly not the case here.  Cheers!

Comment: is a function that is differenciable in C

Comment: I guess I can live with that.  Thanks.

Comment: could you help me with this problem, please?

Comment: i'll post an answer before too long . . . working on it.

Comment: OK, I posted my answer.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

According to a commet of our OP aluno20000 to the question itself, we are to take the words "$f(z)$ is integral" to mean $f(z)$ is differentialble with respect to $z \in \Bbb C$; that is, $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C$ in addition to being $C^2$ on $\Bbb R^2$.

We want to show that

$\nabla^2 \vert f(z) \vert^2 = 4 \vert f'(z) \vert^2; \tag 0$

we have

$f(z) = u(z) + iv(z); \tag{0.1}$

thus,

$\vert f(z) \vert^2 = u^2(z) + v^2(z), \tag{0.2}$

and

$\nabla^2 \vert f(z) \vert^2 = \nabla^2(u^2 + v^2) = \nabla \cdot \nabla (u^2 + v^2)$
$= \nabla \cdot (2u\nabla u + 2v \nabla v) = 2\nabla u \cdot \nabla u + 2u\nabla^2 u + 2\nabla v \cdot \nabla v + 2v\nabla^2 v; \tag 1$

here we have used the well-known identity from [vector calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities),

$\nabla \cdot (\psi \mathbf A) = \nabla \psi \cdot \mathbf A + \psi \nabla \cdot \mathbf A, \tag{1.5}$

taking

$\psi = u, v; \; \mathbf A = \nabla u, \nabla v, \; \text{respectively}; \tag{1.6}$

with $f(z)$ holomorphic, $u$ and $v$ are harmonic:

$\nabla^2 u = \nabla^2 v = 0; \tag 2$

(1) then becomes

$\nabla^2 \vert f(z) \vert^2 = \nabla^2(u^2 + v^2) = 2\nabla u \cdot \nabla u + 2\nabla v \cdot \nabla v; \tag 3$

now,

$\nabla u = (u_x, u_y), \tag 4$

$\nabla v = (v_x, v_y); \tag 5$

since $f(z) = u(z) + iv(z)$, Cauchy-Riemann asserts

$u_x = v_y, \tag 6$

$u_y = -v_x, \tag 7$

whence

$\nabla u \cdot \nabla u = u_x^2 + u_y^2 = u_x^2 + v_x^2 = \vert f'(z) \vert^2; \tag 8$

$\nabla v \cdot \nabla v = v_x^2 + v_y^2 = u_y^2 + v_y^2 = \vert f'(z) \vert^2; \tag 9$

thus,

$ 2\nabla u \cdot \nabla u + 2\nabla v \cdot \nabla v = 4\vert f'(z) \vert^2; \tag {10}$

substitution of this into (3) yields (0).  $OE\Delta$.